# Xcode ncurses text editor example"Error opening terminal: unknown"

Tags: c++, c, xcode, terminal

Im trying to build and run simple ncurses project in XCODE.
ı use command line tool and c language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
```

imported ncurses.h in to my main and ı added the library.
but when ı trying to build and run Xcode give me this error.
How can ı fix this with commend line tool or other way?
I don't know how to use Terminal

Comment: Does `export TERM=vt100` change something?

Comment: İts give me "invalid preprocessing directive" error

Comment: I meant in the shell before starting the executable, set the environmentvariable `TERM` to the value `vt100`

Comment: Learn how to use Terminal. The XCode terminal emulator isn't very full of features. Right-click your application in the project tree. There should be an item similar to "Open directory in Terminal". When Terminal has opened, type `./your_application_name`. (The "./" are important.)

Comment: @Ctx ım sorry ı am new for Xcode can u explain step by step ?

Comment: @molbdnilo ı find this my project name is xca but when ı use your commend ./xca ı mean "-bash: /.xca: No such file or directory" I'm am getting this error

Comment: @haktans4 Did you write `/.` or `./`? They look alike but mean very different things.

Comment: @molbdnilo ı tried bought of them but ı am getting same error ı tried "./xca.xcodeproj" to